# How do I view the size of the data posted to a form in the Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, firebug

I am going through an old ASP.NET app and turning off ViewState for Gridviews where it's not needed. This is reducing the amount of information sent to the server on postback, but I am curious how much.

In FireBug, I can go to the Net tab, apply the HTML filter, and expand the particular aspx file that got posted. Beneath that, I can click the "Post" tab, and one of the values it shows is the Content-Length of the post. (I had some pages uploading 4 megs on postback... YIKES!).

**Does anyone know how to see this value in the Chrome developer tools?**

Comment: I don't think it is in there. You should definitely file a feature request for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Chrome 10, they've added the feature! It's `Content-Length` under the `Request Headers` section in the `Headers` tab. This tab is available when you select `Network` from the toolbar and then click on a file.

I'm going to pretend they did this because I filed the feature request. I changed the world!